# Examples of reductive p-adic groups representations

Tags: representation-theory, p-adic-number-theory, reductive-groups

I am currently reading D. Renard's book "Représentations de groupes réductifs p-adiques". He provides no concrete examples (which would be of great help). I found some notes by Fiona Murnaghan on the subject but they don't cover the Bernstein decomposition. I was hoping someone can point out to a reference with examples (for classical groups for instance) about this particular. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hello @DietrichBurde, I am talking about what the Berstein decomposition looks like for one of the classical groups, like $GL_n(\mathbb{Q}_p)$.

Comment: There are several papers on the Bernstein decomposition of $GL_n(F)$, e.g., [here](https://lmv.math.cnrs.fr/wp-content/uploads/2019/09/pekin.pdf), or on Bernstein's [homepage](http://www.math.tau.ac.il/~bernstei/), but I am not sure if it is helpful.

Comment: Thank you, I found several helpful home-assignments on Bernstein's homepage.